# How to make page shorter when last div is shifted up?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a CSS rule to move the final div on a page up by 30% of the window height, so that it deliberately obscures part of the div above directly it:

```css
div.container {
    top: -30%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Example: [Web page with 30% of an empty screen at the end.](http://www.domaindrain.xyz)

How can I do this without leaving an empty space, at the bottom of the page, which is also 30% of the screen height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add negative margin at the bottom of the container. You can keep `-30%` for that also, though that much is not needed for your case.

```css
div.container {
    top: -30%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: -30%;
}
```

Or, you could achieve same using only `margin-top`:

```css
div.container {
    margin-top: -15%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
}
```